# How to use openaccess to generate domain models through views in the database

Tags: c#, sql-server, telerik

I use sql server as database, then I use Telerik open access to generate domain models through views in the database.

Reading data is Okay, but when I try to update or insert, it doesn't work. I wonder is any configurations that I'm missing. What's the solution you suggest?

I also wonder except openacess, any other good third party software like openaccess, because OpenAccess has become Open Source and Telerik doesn't care it any more.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

I think I almost find a solution, just haven't tested it out.

This needs to use fluent model.